# Как лучше с точки зрения ЧПУ и поисковиков?

Tags: url, seo, чпу, поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация

Никак не решу как лучше ссылки на сайте сделать. Начальник хочет чтобы они хорошо индексировались поисковиками, ну и было достаточно ЧПУ (без фанатизма - транслит не надо). Все простенько:

/конкурс/категория/<статья>|<список>

Т.е. сейчас урлы такие:

```
/contest/1/category/1/article/list
/contest/1/category/1/article/1
/contest/1/category/1/article/list
```

Но начальнику кажется что для поисковика это не оптимально. Предлагает заменить на такие:

```
/contest-1/category-1/article/list
/contest-1/category-1/article-1
/contest-1/category-1/article/list
```

Но по-моему так только хуже. Как лучше сделать эти URL'ы? Мелочь, но хочется все-же сделать как лучше... Вот только по части ЧПУ мы, кажется, не шарим вообще. По моему старый вариант оптимальный, хотя слэшей в нем и правда многовато.

P.S. 1 - это id соответственно конкурса, категории или статьи. Он может меняться.

Comment: Делайте так `/1/1/list`, `/1/1/1` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Можно рассмотреть такой вариант. Вместо id сделайте category name или aliase. И уберите вообще contest, category и article.
В итоге получится что-то вроде TVs/plasma/samsung-s200

Comment: Тоже так считаю. Хотя наверняка найдутся случаи, когда это не уместно.

Comment: Это уже чертов транслит. :( И вообще искать по id куда быстрее чем по названию которое еще и может быть не уникальным.

Comment: @DarkByte но вопрос ведь стоял с точки зрения человекопонятности?

Comment: Вы можете себе для этого дела выделить специальное поле, в которое будете писать уникальное значение. Хоть транслитом хоть нет. Мы делали так: если уникальный код(синоним) прописан, то используем его, если нет, то используем id

Comment: @smellyshovel да, и индексируемости поисковиками тоже! Вот только что понятно одному человеку, не обязательно понятно другому... Меня как-то совсем не смущают id в урлах (с точки зрения пользователя), а вот от транслита в любом виде просто коробит.

Comment: @DarkByte в чем-то с вами согласен. Но ответ имеет право существовать в любом случае.

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно это зависит от главной темы содержания веб-сайта. Если на веб-сайте имеется папка **/не конкурсы/** (упрощенно), то папка **/конкурсы/** может работать. Если на веб-сайте только конкурсные статьи, то отдельную директорию не имеет смысла создавать. О конкурсах можно сообщить в главном и второстепенном описании веб-сайта.

Если все же имеется папка конкурсы, то обозначение этой папки с цифрами мало что поясняет. Вероятно можно применить какую-то смысловую добавку к имени конкурсы, например: конкурсы декабря, или конкурсы 2016 года, или конкурсы в Рязани (локализация) или всё вместе или ещё что-то подобное.

То же самое относиться и категориям. Арифметика здесь не имеет смыслового значения.  Семантически это надо размечать как конкретные наименования категорий. Список категорий и будет вашим **списком-list**, поэтому папка Список-List не нужна. Дочерней и последней папкой здесь может быть ваши *статьи-articles*.

В этом случае будет создана следующая семантическая-навигационная цепь:

***Конкурсы (+ смысловое дополнение. Если только конкурсы, то только смысловое дополнение) --> Категории (+ смысловое дополнение) --> Статья (только название конкретной статьи)***. Пример в виде линка ***contest-Moskva2016-12/maths/primes***.

Такой линк будет соответствовать рекомендациям поисковиков, будет понятен для них и для пользователей и потянет органический трафик на веб-сайт. С безличными именами и арифметикой это будет мало понятно.

Comment: Не стоит столько много полужирного шрифта использовать. Без обид, но в сочетании с тем, что вы не разделяете текст на абзацы, а лепите всё целиком -- читать сложно.